how to infer property and value type from object types
I have an object type; I want to get a new tuple type like: [property, value], when I input the property, them typescript can infer the type of value automatically, but I can't solve the problem.
Example:
type DoubleTuple<T extends Record<any, any>> = T extends Record<infer P, any>
  ? [P, T[P]]
  : never;

interface ExampleModel {
  a: number;
  b: string;
}
// when i input the property 'a', number | string was inferred , but number expected
const tuple: DoubleTuple<ExampleModel> = ["a", "3"];


• There are no obvious mapped types in this question. Where is the "mapped type"? Maybe you're using unconventional terminology? • DoubleTuple doesn't propertly distribute over unions in P.  You need a distributive object type as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

This answer is fantastic, why can't I think of it！However, for me, "mapped type" is a "Record<K, V>" or "Map<K, V>" type, which may be a misunderstanding of mine

You want DoubleTuple<T> type to be a union of entry tuple types for each key-value pair in T.  So DoubleTuple<{a: A, b: B, c: C}> should be ["a", A] | ["b", B] | ["c", C].  But your version doesn't do that at all.
First, T extends Record<infer P, any> ? P : never is equivalent to just keyof T (unless T is a union, but that doesn't seem to be your use case), so you can collapse your type to [keyof T, T[keyof T]], which mixes all the keys and properties together. Really you want to distribute your operation over the elements of keyof T, so that it looks like [P, T[P]] for each P in keyof T.
There are different ways to accomplish this but a common one is to build a distributive object type as coined in microsoft/TypeScript#47109. It's of the form {[P in K]: F<P>}[K] where K is some union of keylike types (such as keyof T). This produces a mapped type into which you immediately index to get the union of F<P> for each P in K.
That gives us the following:
type DoubleTuple<T extends Record<any, any>> = 
   { [P in keyof T]: [P, T[P]] }[keyof T];

Let's test it out:
interface ExampleModel {
  a: number;
  b: string;
}
   
type DTEM = DoubleTuple<ExampleModel>;
// type DTEM = ["a", number] | ["b", string]

let tuple: DoubleTuple<ExampleModel>;
tuple = ["a", 2]; // okay
tuple = ["a", "x"]; // error
tuple = ["b", "x"]; // okay
tuple = ["b", 2]; // error

Looks good.
Playground link to code
